# Detect If DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges Ran?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using a CodeFirst approach using EF5.

I was looking at running a DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to fix the database if my model changes, but there is data that needs to be repopulated when it does run.

I figure that I can do an entity count to see if it was run, but I am curious if there was a more elegant way to do this? (Some kind of return value or event that I can have my code look for)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also can avoid this problem with Migrations: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx - if you do not know, take a look, it is neat :)

Comment: Wow thank you. Just read through it, will have to digest it more but looks like a good approach for once I get out of development. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to derive from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and override the [Seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679410%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method to add data to the context for seeding when the DB is recreated:

```
public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>
{

    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        context.AddSomeInitialData();
        context.SaveChanges();        
    }

}
```

And on your application start set it as the Database initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInitializer());
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems so obvious now!